# Использование ключевого слова typename

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

**1) Шаблонная функция:**

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

**2) Шаблонний клас:**

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    T data;
    int arr[10];
};
```

**3) Если тип зависит от параметра шаблона:**

```
template<typename T>
void for_each(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    for(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); it++)
    *it = *it + *it; 
}
```

Какие есть еще случаи использования `typename` ?

Comment: Usage: • In a template declaration, typename can be used as an alternative to class to declare type template parameters and template template parameters (since C++17).  • Inside a declaration or a definition of a template, typename can be used to declare that a dependent name is a type. • Inside a requirements for type requirements (since C++20). ([Отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename))

Comment: Если проще, то везде, где нужно компилятору указывать, что это имя типа, а то он не поймет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы между вариантами 1 и 2. С таким же успехом можно было вынести использование `typename` в шаблонных псевдонимах и в шаблонных переменных в отдельные "варианты"

```
template <typename T> using MyVector = std::vector<T, MyAllocator>;
template <typename T> constexpr T PI = 3.14159;
```

Все эти "варианты" - это один вариант. Во всех этих случаях `typename` используется одинаково: для объявления типового параметра шаблона.

4. Начиная с C++17 ключевое слово `typename` может использоваться вместо ключевого слова `class` в объявлениях шаблонных параметров шаблонов

   ```
   template <typename T, template <typename, typename> typename CONT>
   //                                                  ^^^^^^^^ 
   class MyClass
   {
     CONT<T, std::allocator<T>> container;
   };
   ```

   До C++17 второй параметр этого шаблона должен был бы объявляться как

   ```
   template <typename, typename> class CONT
   //                            ^^^^^
   ```

Comment: Вроде `typename` и до этого можно было использовать так. Но это msvc 15 и 17 с с++14.

Comment: @MrBin cppreference.com однозначно помечает такое использование как С++17 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). GCC тоже допускает его только в режиме C++17.

Comment: Кстати, только узнал, что можно имена не ставить - а смысл тогда от шаблонов? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/953014/178988